# MethodName as typed parameter without method parameters

Tags: c#, moq

Is it possible to create a method that takes a MethodName as a typed parameter.  I'm after compile time checking for the name of the method.  I know I can do the following -- passing in a string of the method name:

```
public static DoStuff<TType>(Mock<TType> mockType, string methodName)
{
    var methods = mockType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                          .Where(method => method.Name == methodName && method.ReturnType == typeof(TResult))
                          .ToList();
    // ...
}
```

And used:

```
var myType = new Mock<MyType>();
myType.DoStuff("Update");
```

But is there a way to do something like:

```
var myType = new myType();
myType.DoStuff(m => m.Update)
```

Where it is evaluated at compilation and would throw if 'Update' doesn't exist on the Type 'MyType'.

Thanks.

Comment: Parameters is part of method's signature, so it is somewhat expected that you pass/specify them when using method. I.e. what if there are 2 `Update` with 5 and 7 arguments when you expect `Update` with 2 arguments? I assume you've looked at Moq way of specifying arguments (with `It.IsAny<T>()`) which is likely what caused the question - consider commenting on it.

Comment: Yep -- I'm attempting to make a 'helper' function that allows setting the return value for method `methodName` without having to manually specify all of the `It.IsAny<T>()` parameters.  It's working fine with the string `methodName`, I was wondering if I could improve on it.  It currently throws if > 1 method is found with the same `methodName` + `returnValue`, and in that scenario, I would revert to using the standard `Setup` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. You can't get compile-time checking unless you specify an actual generic parameter, which requires knowing the type at compile time.

Comment: Consider adding reasons (maybe "parameters are part of signature" or "C# templates are not C++ templates when it comes to signature matching") to make answer more convincing.